# Save/load compiled Regex in Rust?

Tags: regex, serialization, rust, deserialization

I'm working on some application where performance is critical and i'm looking for opportunities to improve it. The app uses regular expressions extensively ([regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.5/regex/)), eg.:

```
use regex::Regex;
...
let Regex = Regex::new(r###"[a-z0-9%]{3,}"###).unwrap();
```

Is there any opportunity to save a precompiled `Regex` instance to a buffer (think `Vec<u8>`) and load later pre-compiled to avoid multiple compilations (can't see anything similar in the [docs](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.5/regex/))?

PS. I already do it lazily with:

```
    lazy_static! {
        static ref REGEX2: Regex = Regex::new(r###"[a-z0-9%]{3,}"###).unwrap();
    }
```

trying to save some CPU cycles if having multiple invocations (but that's another story).

PS. Just out of curiosity i've benchmarked the code:

```
fn bench_regex_candidates(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        Regex::new(r###"[a-z0-9%]{3,}"###).unwrap();
    });
}

fn bench_regex_content(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        Regex::new(r###"^([^*|@"!]*?)#([@?$])?#(.+)$"###).unwrap()
    });
}
```

and the compilation is fast (relatively, for my needs):

```
regex/candidates        time:   [22.021 us 22.684 us 23.689 us]                              
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild
  9 (9.00%) high severe
regex/content           time:   [36.542 us 36.687 us 36.845 us]                           
Found 8 outliers among 100 measurements (8.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  5 (5.00%) high severe
```

Comment: It is an interesting question indeed. I don't think there is a good way of doing it without incurring in some unsafe chronicles. Lets see If someone surprise us!

Comment: Is your build time being negatively impacted by regex compilation in a meaningful way?

Comment: @tadman It's not about build time but application run time - regexp can be compiled once and then reused or even precompiled and bundled right to the app. Also the regexp can come in runtime, so we could distribute precompiled regex instead of text representation

Comment: How many of these do you have? Unless it's > 10K I hardly doubt you could even measure the time necessary to instantiate them. When exploring performance issues like this it can help to make your code really "stupid" on purpose, like do 100x more work than you need, just to see if it actually slows anything down. Often it doesn't.

Comment: This question boils down to "Can you serialize/deserialize a regular expression in Rust" and I think the answer is "No", at least currently.

Comment: @tadman >"How many of these do you have?" 31. >"Unless it's > 10K I hardly doubt you could even measure the time necessary to instantiate them". I can `cargo bench` it to have the exact answer. Any reason to think it's impossible in general (save/load)?

Comment: 31 is such a trifling number I bet their instantiation time is at most ~1ms, but you could benchmark with and without then to find out. I think it's impossible because unless you have thousands of these and they're all quite convoluted it's a non-problem.

Comment: I'm not able to predict the future, but I think having these compiled to machine code is possible and not unlikely, so serialization would actually be a step backwards. If the core Rust team doesn't do it, I'd expect a crate could. It'd be one dizzyingly complex macro, but it's theoretically possible.

Comment: Objectively I think the solution here is to not use regular expressions and instead do the parsing yourself as code. That's always faster, though can take a lot more fussing to implement correctly.

Comment: i agree manually written code is faster. BTW i've updated my question with benchmarks that show it's fast actually (meaning there is no huge sense in doing that in most of cases).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that no, you cannot. Something like this has to be provided by the `regex` crate itself. There is an open issue tracking it: https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/258

It's unlikely a feature like this will be supported any time soon. Generally speaking, there are two ways that the `regex` crate could go about this. The first would be to simply serialize its internal data structures using Serde. The second would be to make the internal implementation congruent to a bespoke serialized structure.

In the first case, the implementation effort of the naive approach probably isn't too bad, and could likely be accomplished by sprinkling a few `derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)` in a few places. There are two main problems with this approach. Firstly, it requires an explicit serialization step that will have costs of its own, and it's not clear whether it would be meaningfully faster than regex compilation itself in enough cases. Secondly, this would expose internal data structures as a public API guarantee. So in actuality, implementing this would probably require choosing a format that we could commit to. This would in turn likely require yet another translation step before serialization and after deserialization, increasing costs. So overall, this approach requires a fair amount of effort and it's not clear whether it's worth it.

The second approach would make serialization and deserialization effectively free, because the internal representation would be the serialized form. This suffers from the same "public API" format guarantee of the first problem, so it would have to be done carefully in order to manage compatibility guarantees. The other main problem with this approach is that it infects the entirety of the internal implementation. Effectively, everything must be written with this sort of constraint in mind. Internal pointers, for example, could no longer be used. So there is a big trade off in code complexity required to do this. And it's also a lot of work.

Others have mentioned benchmarking your code. You should do this, and this question would be a much better question if you could carefully justify why you need to *eliminate* the compilation cost. Just because you're writing a high performance application and you're using regexes compiled with pattern strings at runtime doesn't mean regex compilation is itself a bottleneck. It absolutely *could* be, but it's also pretty likely that it *isn't*. Therefore, it's really important to check this assumption. Ideally, you would create a minimal benchmark program that reproduces the same usage patterns of your application, and then measure which aspects of your program use the majority of the time.

With all that said, the [`regex-automata` crate does support (de)serializing regexes](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.9/regex_automata/#example-deserialize-a-dfa), and it does so using the second approach I outlined above. However, `regex-automata` is not a general purpose regex engine and [there are severe differences between it and the `regex` crate](https://docs.rs/regex-automata/0.1.9/regex_automata/#differences-with-the-regex-crate). For example, it would not be appropriate to use `regex-automata` to compile regexes with pattern strings derived from user input, since compilation could take exponential time in the size of the pattern.